# Why .tfignore doesnt work at all?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I followed the instructions in [this Microsoft article](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control), but they don't work.

I created .tfignore file, put it in the root, here its content (**I want to exclude these folders**).

[image]

When I open Team Explorer - Pending Changes, I see these folders **are included** in Pending Changes

[image]

Comment: Are you using a server workspace? `.tfignore` only works with local workspaces. Also, are the files already in source control? If they are, `.tfignore` won't apply to them.

Comment: Daniel, no, local. Yes, they are in TFS. I dont want to check them in every time I compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tfignore not working in VS 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207577/tfignore-not-working-in-vs-2013)

Comment: What's the type of your project? Asp.Net Core?

Answer (score 2):

A way to solve the issue is updating your VS to **[VS2015Update 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/06/27/visual-studio-2015-update-3-and-net-core-1-0-available-now/)**. The `.tfignore` should be indeed working correctly.

If  those files **already in the pending changes** before you add your `.tfigonre` file in source control. You can try below solution:

> If the changes are "still" in pending changes, first create a backup
>   copy, then make an Undo on them. Close VS, restore the backup copies
>   and then it should work.

Or you can try to use a *temporary quick fix* for the problem:
Add an `$` char into the bower_components folder name in the .bowerrc. TFS does not allow the `$` character in the file name, so it can't be added to source control.

More detail ways you can refer this blog from GitHub: [Things in ".tfignore" still are shown in pending changes](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/18)

Comment: I cant update VS, we are in a corporate environment here