# TFS/VS 2013 - Ignore ALL NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I'm using TFS and Visual Studio 2013. Whenever there are changes regarding the packages we use, TFS tries to add those binaries to Source Control. If you don't pay attention, you check in a ton of binaries. On the other hand, if you exclude those, you will have an enormous amount of excluded items all over the place - which are displayed in the pending-check-ins view.

I tried adding a .tfignore file to the root of the repository:

```
######################################
# Ignore all files in the packages sub-folder
\packages
packages\
\packages\
```

...to no effect. Deleting the packaged folder all over again in every *workspace* is just annoying as hell.

Is there a way to configure TFS/VS or whatever to ignore those folders? There has to be one, since /bin, /obj, etc are ignored as well.