# TFS keeps adding my NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, nuget, tfignore

I have a few projects using numerous NuGet packages and these projects are source controlled on TFS. Whenever the packages are restored, they are automatically readded to source control.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and TFS 2013 with local workspaces and my NuGet version is 2.8.50313.46.

I am apparently not the only one to have this issue. Quite an amount of people have been asking this on StackOverflow but none of them were able to solve this issue **or at least not with new implementation of package restore in NuGet**. I tried the .tfignore in solution folder with '/packages' exclusion but it did not work either. So I am now asking for help here because sooner or later, someone is gonna checkin those files!

Thanks.

Note: There is about 20 users using this TFS, so applying an individual fix on each machine is not something I am looking into.

Comment: There are some answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604506/tfs-vs-2013-ignore-all-nuget-packages/26618439#26618439). Mine is the only one the works 100% of the time for me and my colleagues - despite the downvote :).

Comment: It surely works but you cannot apply this if it is used by 20 users!

Comment: .tfignore works for me

Comment: Are you sure that you're using local workspaces?  Can you post a screenshot of the workspace edit dialog (with the Advanced options)?  Can you post your `tfignore`?

Comment: @EdwardThomson - are you open to discussing this elsewhere. We have tried a lot of things.

Comment: @Ucodia - we do it for >100 :)

Comment: @DaveShaw I don't work on TFVC, but I can take your feedback to those who do.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I will verify when I go home and give you feedback.

Comment: @DaveShaw Ah it surely works, but then there will always be one moment where someone will have a different workspace setting and commit the packages!

Comment: Yep, it happens. I just delete them again. I've had an e mail from Ed and he has confirmed that .tfignore files are ignored (ironically)

Comment: @EdwardThomson I rechecked and I am really using a local workspace.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Is this bug being logged somewhere on Connect?

Answer (score 3):

You can add to your solution new folder called ".nuget", under the folder put file called "NuGet.config", inside the file add the nuget configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
</configuration>
```

For more information: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the solution folder -> enable nuget package restore on build. 
That will create the required configuration, and also enable other team members to build the project automatically.

then you should commit the project. make sure to delete all packages. and then if possible try a new checkout on each machine.

Comment: "Enable nuget package restore on build" is outdated after Nuget 2.7. See http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore