# How to ignore files in jspm_packages - .tfignore does not seem to work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfvc

I have a single page app with a really large jspm_packages folder, all of which I would like to get TFS to ignore.  I have placed a .tfignore file in the jspm_packages directory. It has "*.*" as the file contents to ignore everything.

However, it still tries to include them.  I have "Excluded" them, but I would like to permanently exclude them.

Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Are you using a Local or Server workspace? (do you have to check out to edit?)

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the folder in Visual Studio checkin windows and selecting "exclude"?

Comment: Yes, and it does exclude them from checking in.  But I would prefer not to have to exclude them every day.  The idea is that tfignore would completely ignore them.  Having 30,000 files to exclude each time is a bit much.

Comment: Once in exclude you can then mark them, or their parent folder as "ignore". This will put the correct entry into the .tfignore file.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is here: [tfIgnore does not work for me in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416407/tfignore-does-not-work-for-me-in-visual-studio-2013)

The point I missed is that if the items are already added to the Source Control, the .tfignore will not undo that.  Instead, right click the folder you which to exclude and select Undo to undo the Add.  After that is achieved, then the .tfignore will keep them out of source control.

Comment: I am not sure why you would expect it to work any other way? If you have explicitly added it to source control it can't be ignored.